# Why am I not able to push a pair after a limit in the vector?

Tags: c++, vector

The problem is to find if a given sequence of numbers can form a valid permutation or not. The problem statement is trivial for the real problem. So, I am pushing a pair of integers into the vector. The first part being the number itself and second being 0 or 1.

The code works fine till a sequence 1041 long (specific after debugging a lot). Just to debug I added a print statement after pushing each pair inside the vector. For a length of 1042, the code shows pushed 1040 and then pushed 1 (which is weird) and then just hangs on there.

I am attaching the code as well as the input and terminal output.

**You can just check the main function**

*Code*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

bool comparator_function(pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b) {
    return (a.first < b.first);
}

//index_added -> the index at which the latest element was added
void set_r_array(int* r_array_ref, int* per_array_ref, int size, int* count, int index_added) {

    for(int i = 1;i <= size; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    int temp = index_added;

    while(index_added <= size) {
        if(index_added == size) {
            if(per_array_ref[index_added] == 0) {
                r_array_ref[temp] = size;
                break;
            }
            else {
                r_array_ref[temp] = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(per_array_ref[index_added] == 0) {
                r_array_ref[temp] = index_added;
                break;
            }
            else {
                index_added++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1;i <= size; i++) {
        if(r_array_ref[i] != -1) {
            count[r_array_ref[i]]++;
        }
    }
}

bool check_max(int* count, int next_element, int size) {

    int max_count = -1, index = 0;

    for(int i = 1;i <= size; i++) {
        int temp_val = count[i];
        if(max_count <= temp_val) {
            max_count = temp_val;
            index = i;
        }
    }

    int num = 0;

    for(int i = 1;i <= size; i++) {
        if(count[i] == max_count) {
            num++;
        }
    }

    //one max
    if(num == 1) {
        if(next_element == index) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    else {
        for(int i = 1;i <= size; i++) {
            if(count[i] == max_count) {
                if(next_element == i) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    int testCases;

    cin >> testCases;
    cin.ignore();

    while(testCases-- > 0) {
        int n, result_flag = 0;
        cin >> n;
        cin.ignore();
        vector<pair<int, int>> per;
        int temp;

        for(int i = 0;i < n; i++) {
            cin >> temp;
            pair<int, int> temp_pair = make_pair(temp, i+1);
            per.push_back(temp_pair);
            //debug statement
            cout << "pushed " << temp << endl;
        }

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        cout << "start" << endl;

        sort(per.begin(), per.end(), comparator_function);

        int permutation_array[n+1], r_array[n+1], count[n+1];
        for(int i = 0;i <= n; i++) {
            permutation_array[i] = 0;
            r_array[i] = i;
            count[i] = 1;
        }

        cout << "end" << endl;

        permutation_array[per[0].second] = per[0].first;
        set_r_array(r_array, permutation_array, n, count, per[0].second);

        //insertion of numbers
        for(int i = 1;i < n; i++) {
            //check if the next element inserted has the largest count rn or not
            int next_element = per[i].second;
            if(!check_max(count, next_element, n)) {
                cout << "No" << endl;
                result_flag = -1;
                break;
            }

            permutation_array[per[i].second] = per[i].first;
            set_r_array(r_array, permutation_array, n, count, per[i].second);
        }

        if(result_flag == 0) {
            cout << "Yes" << endl;
        }

        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);

        cout << "Time: " << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;
    }
}
```

*Input 1*

```
1
5
2 3 4 5 1
```

*Output 1*

```
pushed 2
pushed 3
pushed 4
pushed 5
pushed 1
start
end
Yes
```

*Input 2*

```
1
1042
1 2 3 4 ... so on till 1042
```

*Output 2*

```
pushed 1
pushed 2
.
.
.
pushed 1040
pushed 1

and then hangs, from here on
```

The complexity of the code is O(n^2). So, I don't think it has to do anything with that. Since the input can be at max 10^4 order. Moreover, according to the print debugging, I think the issue is with the input.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212478/discussion-on-question-by-sukrit-kapil-why-am-i-not-able-to-push-a-pair-after-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue with input as you reach console line limit.

Put your input into a file should solve that issue.

Then you should be able to debug your algorithm which seems more complicated than needed.